# Function orthogonal to $|y-x|$ on $[0,1]$ for every $y \in [0,1]$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integral-kernel

Does there exist an essentially nonzero function $f:[0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ so that
$$
\int_0^1 |y-x| f(x) \, dx = 0
$$
for every $y \in [0,1]$?  I think I see how to show that any such $f$ can't be continuous at any $x$ for which $f(x) \neq 0$ (since, if $K_y(x) := |y-x|$, then $-2K_y + K_{y - \epsilon} + K_{y + \epsilon}$ is positive on $[y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon]$ but zero elsewhere), but does there still exist any measurable $f$ with the above property?

Answer (score 5):

No, linear combinations of functions of the form $|x-y|$ are dense in $C([0, 1])$ (because you can approximate any continuous function by the piecewise-linear), so (if $f\in L^1(0,1)$, otherwise the integral may not exist)  $f$ is orthogonal to all continuous functions, hence almost everywhere zero.

Comment: I didn't really read or think about the problem, but why are you assuming $f \in L^1$? You say the integral may not exist otherwise, but so?

Comment: @mathworker21 : Since $|0-x|+|1-x|=1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, we have $\int_0^1 f=0$, so that $f\in L^1$.

Comment: Excellent, that does it.  Thanks!